# Solvable Schrödinger operator

Tags: operator-theory

I am currently looking for an example of a 1-dimensional Schrödinger Operator $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x)$ with the following properties:

1) V(x) must be integrable

2) $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +V(x)$ must have some negative eigenvalues

3) The operator should be solvable, i.e. the (negative) eigenvalues should be exactly (i.e. analytically) known.

I want to test a numerical method for the computation of eigenvalues of such operators, but unfortunately I am lacking a solvable example for these tests (and searching for one didn't get me anywhere). I would appreciate any help.

Comment: you may want to look up Morse Potential.

Comment: Try solitons perhaps.